# how to run a json object in bootstrap-table (key: value)

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

How can I represent the following json object in bootstrap-table

```
{
  "SourceFile": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/metaviewer/uploads/2438071792_19ed1df293_o.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 10.8,
  "FileName": "2438071792_19ed1df293_o.jpg",
  "Directory": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/metaviewer/uploads",
  "FileSize": "123 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FileInodeChangeDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-r--r--",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "FileTypeExtension": "jpg",
}
```

I want to represent a column with the (key) and the next column with the (value) of the json object but that is recursive, that does not have to be specified in the value field, that works for N key records: value

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem based on https://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/2556/

```js
var objectJson = {
  "SourceFile": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/metaviewer/uploads/2438071792_19ed1df293_o.jpg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 10.8,
  "FileName": "2438071792_19ed1df293_o.jpg",
  "Directory": "/opt/lampp/htdocs/metaviewer/uploads",
  "FileSize": "123 kB",
  "FileModifyDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FileInodeChangeDate": "2019:07:01 21:59:19-05:00",
  "FilePermissions": "rw-r--r--",
  "FileType": "JPEG",
  "FileTypeExtension": "jpg"
}

function responseHanlder(res) {
  var data = [];
  for (var key in res) {
      data.push({
          key: key,
          value: res[key]
      });
  }
  return data;
}

$(function () {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
      field: 'key',
      title: 'key name'
    }, {
      field: 'value',
      title: 'value name'
    }],
      data: responseHanlder(objectJson)
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table id="table"> </table>
```

enter code here